# Python Append Microseconds to date element of the list

Tags: python, list, datetime, append

Hello I have a list of data generated as below

l_ele = line.split()

```
['2014-02-10T15:57:00.400733+00:00', 'coccus1','info="processing"]
['2014-02-10T15:57:02.734042+00:00', 'coccus1' , info="processing"]
['2014-02-10T15:57:02+00:00','coccus1','info="processing"']
['2014-02-10T15:57:03+00:00', 'coccus1','info="looking for match"']
['2014-02-10T15:57:04+00:00', 'coccus1', info="sampling"
['2014-02-10T15:57:06.771501+00:00','coccus1','info="sampling"']
```

I would like to append the ssssss to 000000 bit to the dateelement of the list if it does not have it.How to achieve it ?

Expected Output:

```
['2014-02-10T15:57:00.400733+00:00', 'coccus1','info="processing"]
['2014-02-10T15:57:02.734042+00:00', 'coccus1' , info="processing"]
['2014-02-10T15:57:02.000000+00:00','coccus1','info="processing"']
['2014-02-10T15:57:03.000000+00:00', 'coccus1','info="looking for match"']
['2014-02-10T15:57:04.000000+00:00', 'coccus1', info="sampling"
['2014-02-10T15:57:06.771501+00:00','coccus1','info="sampling"']
```

Comment: Is each of those lines a list?

Comment: @msvalkon  every line is a list

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what format your data is in, but assuming two strings:

```
s1 = "2014-02-10T15:57:02+00:00"
s2 = "2014-02-10T15:57:02.734042+00:00"
```

you can ensure they both match formats by doing:

```
def process_string(s):
    return s if len(s) == 32 else "".join((s[:-6], ".000000", s[-6:]))
```

Or, in Python pre-2.5:

```
def process_string:
    if len(s) == 32:
        return s
    return "".join((s[:-6], ".000000", s[-6:]))
```

Examples:

```
>>> process_string(s1)
'2014-02-10T15:57:02.000000+00:00'
>>> process_string(s2)
'2014-02-10T15:57:02.734042+00:00'
```

Ordinarily, I would recommend using `datetime` to do this, but your timezone offset is not in the format supported by `strptime`.

---

To apply this to the first item in each list, simply access it by index, for example:

```
>>> l = ['2014-02-10T15:57:02+00:00', 'coccus1','info="processing"']
>>> l[0] = process_string(l[0])
>>> l
['2014-02-10T15:57:02.000000+00:00', 'coccus1', 'info="processing"']
```

Comment: Hi jonrshare the time stamps are in ISOformat and every line is split to be a list how can i extend it to deal with list elements ?

Comment: Updated to cover updating a list. The timezone format directive `'%z'` in `strptime` takes "UTC offset in the form `+HHMM` or `-HHMM`", no colons; I don't know why.

Comment: Thanks a lot Iam using python  2.4.3 it is giving a syntax error :( at if in the code return s if len(s) == 32 else "".join((s[:-6], ".000000", s[-6:]))